# Improper base64url

Tags: node.js

The JWT guide here - https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token#header - says they run `base64url` on this:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}
```

And they end up with this:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
```

I try this code:

```
var b64u = require("base64url")
var rez = b64u(JSON.stringify({
      "typ": "JWT",
      "alg": "HS256"
}));
var shouldbe = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9';
console.log(rez);
console.log(shouldbe);
console.log(rez == shouldbe);
```

as seen here in online test:
https://tonicdev.com/56c5484d7a4ea10d0002c623/5733af59234d9d1200d8c818

however they are not matching.

Does anyone see any simple issue?

Comment: I think their example is wrong. I also get `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9`. Side note, you don't need the `base64url` module to base64 encode things. Just do `new Buffer(str).toString('base64');, where `str` is your stringified JSON.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @dvlsg

Comment: Oh you know what, I wonder if `JSON.stringify` is switching the order of `alg` and `typ` keys. I noticed the scotch.io tutorial has them non-alphabetically.

Comment: I get `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9` when I use a string that has `alg` first, followed by `typ`. Take a look at https://jwt.io/ as well. They have a breakdown of each piece of the JWT.

Comment: Thanks so much @dvlsg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Base64 output is dependent on which order of keys you receive in the string from the `JSON.stringify` call.

For reference, here is a working example using pre-built JSON strings.

```
let expected = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9';

let str1 = '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}';
let str2 = '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}';

// note that you don't need a library to Base64 encode strings in node
let base64str1 = new Buffer(str1).toString('base64');
let base64str2 = new Buffer(str2).toString('base64');

console.log(base64str1); // 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9'
console.log(base64str2); // 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9'
console.log('base64str1 equals expected?', base64str1 === expected); // true
console.log('base64str2 equals expected?', base64str2 === expected); // false
```

Comment: I think a lot of the time libraries / guides accidentally take for granted the fact that object keys are not guaranteed to be sorted in any way. Here's another good [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) that goes into more detail.